# Multi session chat server in C

Tags: c, network-programming

I am trying to write a multi session chat server in C. I host the server from one terminal and telnet to it from other terminals. 
Using ubuntu 13.04 on VMWare player.

What happens is this: 
I'm incrementing a loop from 3 onward to fdmax, to accept new connections using sd ( the listener) and newsd represents the new socket descriptor.

When I print 'hi' in one window, it prints in ALL windows including the one I typed in. Plus, a lot of random junk keeps appearing.
I want only what I type to appear(how do i get rid of the junk>), and in all the windows except the one I typed it in!

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/select.h>

void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
  if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET)
  {
    return &(((struct sockaddr_in*) sa)->sin_addr);
  }

  return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*) sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  //ptr used for traversal, serv used for the linked list of struct addinfos , hints for      the getaddrinfo function
  struct addrinfo *ptr, hints, *serv;
  int max_cli, dat, x, i;
  struct sockaddr_storage cli_addr;
  socklen_t addr_size;
  char cli_ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
  char inc[256]; //one command line is 80 characters
  memset(inc, 0, strlen(inc));
  int sd, newsd;
  fd_set master;
  fd_set read_fds;
  char value[256];

  FD_ZERO(&master);
  FD_ZERO(&read_fds);

  //argv[1]-server ip argv[2]-server port argv[3]-maximum client number

  int fdmax;
  int opt = 1;

  /*if(argc!=4)
   {
   printf("Please re-enter data. Data insufficient\n");
   exit(1);
   }
   if(atoi(argv[2])<1025)
   {
   printf("Reserved port. Please try again\n");
   exit(1);
   }*/
  max_cli = atoi(argv[3]);

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

  /* Verify the inputs and generate linked list of possible IPs to use*/

  if (sd = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &serv))
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error calling getaddrinfo %s\n", gai_strerror(sd));
    exit(1);
  }

  for (ptr = serv; ptr != NULL ; ptr = ptr->ai_next)
  {

    void *addr;
    if (ptr->ai_family == AF_INET)
    {
      struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *) ptr->ai_addr;
      addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
    }
    inet_ntop(ptr->ai_family, addr, value, sizeof value);
    //printf("%s\n",value);     

    //Form connection with one of the IP addresses   
    sd = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (sd < 0)
      continue;

    setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof opt);

    if (bind(sd, ptr->ai_addr, ptr->ai_addrlen) < 0)
    {
      close(sd);
      continue;
    }

    break; //Indicates one working socket found and bound
  } //end for

  if (ptr == NULL )
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Bind failed\n");
    exit(2);
  }

  freeaddrinfo(serv);

  if (listen(sd, 15) == -1)
  {
    printf("Error occurred while listening\n");
    exit(3);
  }

  /* Socket found, bound and now listening for active connections*/

  FD_SET(sd, &master);

  fdmax = sd; //Latest active socket descriptor

  while (1)
  {

    read_fds = master; //Copy the master list so that the original list doesn't get damaged

    if (select(fdmax + 1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL ) == -1)
    {
      perror("Select failed.\n");
      exit(4);
    }

    for (i = 3; i <= fdmax; i++)
    {
      //printf("i");
      //printf("entered for loop\n");
      if (FD_ISSET(i,&read_fds))    //new connection->false, existing one->true
      {
        //  printf("Started reading descriptors!\n");

        if (i == sd)    //primary connection,exists, accept new file descriptor
        { //printf("Read first connection!\n");
          addr_size = sizeof cli_addr;
          newsd = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &addr_size);
          printf("Accepted new connection socket %d\n", newsd);
          FD_SET(newsd, &master);
          if (newsd == -1)
          {
            perror("accept");
          }
          if (newsd > fdmax)
          {
            fdmax = newsd;
          }
          printf("%d %d\n", newsd, fdmax);
          continue;
        }
        else if (i != sd) //existing connection, so accept data
        {
          if (dat = recv(i, &inc, sizeof inc, 0) <= 0)
          {
            if (dat == 0)
            {
              printf(" Socket %d has quit the   chatroom", i);
            }
            if (dat < 0)
            {
              perror("Error on Receive");
            }
            //  char *s=&inc;
            //printf("%d\n %s",dat);
            close(i);
            FD_CLR(i, &master);
          }

          //Nothing wrong with the input from client i.  Broadcast!
          else
          {
            for (x = 3; x <= fdmax; x++)
            {
              if (FD_ISSET(x,&master))
              {
                if (x != sd)
                {
                  //send(x,&inc,sizeof inc,0);
                  if (send(x, &inc, sizeof inc, 0) < 0)
                  {
                    perror("Send");
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }

      }

      /*else// new connection
       { break;

       printf("SERVERBOT: new connection from %s on socket %d\n",inet_ntop(cli_addr.ss_family,get_in_addr((struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr),cli_ip, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN),newsd);
       }////change this to 'username' has joined the room*/

    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the source - unlikely.

Comment: @viraptor I am so sorry :| just printed it

Comment: What are the problems you are having, do you want the message to display in all of the connections, or just in the ones that do not send it?

Comment: What is 'random junk'?

Comment: @Justin Wood: I want the message to appear in all except the one that sends it. If I type 'hi' in one terminal, I get the hi in all terminals, but a bunch or junk appears as well! Why is the junk appearing and what can I do to make sure only the 'hi' appears?

Comment: @JustinWood: I meant junk, sorry. Strange non-alphanumeric symbols, actually.

Comment: About junk, are you sure you add terminating `'/0'` to data before printing, or otherwise prevent buffer overrun? And when sending, are you sure you never send a fixed size buffer which is partially uninitialized, or something like that? Also remember, you use stream protocol, it has no packet boundaries, code accordingly (maybe you do, did not read your code that well...).

Comment: @hyde: Do I need to add a terminating '\0' to the data? I'm not printing it, I've only used send. And the buffer is of fixed size. SHould I change it to just char inc? instead of inc[256]?
I do use memset to set the string to all zeros.

Comment: When sending, you should send just the data you received, and when printing, you should print just the data you received too. `sizeof` operator gives you size of whole buffer, it does not care about contents (C arrays do not have dynamic size, you have to keep track of that yourself).

Comment: @hyde, Thanks. I missed that on the man page. I'll try that now

Comment: @hyde After making that change from
send(x,&inc,sizeof inc,0);
to
send(x,&inc,dat,0);
It's not printing anything :|

Comment: @hyde, it works, I made some further edits. Can I upvote you? I don't know how this works

Comment: @tvishwa107 I wrote comment contents as answer, you can accept and optionally upvote that.

Comment: what does a debugger say is happening

Comment: @pm100, it worked once I replaced sizeof inc with dat.

Comment: Unless your goal is specifically to learn the BSD stuff yourself, you may want to look into [libevent](http://libevent.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you send received data, you use `sizeof` operator, which gives you total size of array. You should send just as many bytes as you received, which will often be less. Use return value of `recv` to know how many bytes were actually received. In general, C arrays do not have dynamic size, you have to keep track of that yourself.

Then about garbage, you probably print buffer contents without terminating `'\0'` character. So, either add that (make sure there is the 1 byte of extra space in the buffer!) before printing or using other string functions, or use a printing function which accepts maximum size of string in case that terminating nul is missing.

Comment: I can't upvote, but this worked fine for me. Thanks. Btw, don't you mean '\0'?

Comment: Fixed the slash. And yeah, upvoting needs a bit of reputation, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

for a start your send must use dat as length not sizeof(inc)